# Why is this Django model method not added to the model class?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a simple model named Ingredient which multiple profiles (instances of the class IngredientProfile) can be linked to.

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'ingrediente')

    def get_default_profile(self):
        try:
            return self.profiles.get(default=True).name
        except:
            return 'N/A'


class IngredientProfile(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('ingredient', 'default')

    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, related_name='profiles', verbose_name=u'ingrediente')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name=u'profilo')
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=u'predefinito')
```

Is there any reason for the Ingredient model not showing the get_default_profile method at runtime?

If I call the method on a model instance I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Ingredient' object has no attribute 'get_default_profile'
```

Woodoo?

Comment: You show the code where you define the function and that's good. Can you also show the code where you try to **use** the function, as well as the complete traceback ? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using it as a class method? eg. `Ingredient.get_default_profile()`.

Comment: @jpic I started debugging from a template not showing the return value from a standard {{ ingredient.get_default_profile }} and then inspected with the Django shell, importing the Ingredient model, creating an instance, and looking into the imported method and attributes. dir(Ingredient) just like dir(i), i being an instance of Ingredient, don't show the method.

Comment: @RickyA No, I'm using it on an instance, the class doesn't show the method either.

Comment: Try deleting your .pyc files. Maybe still uses an old one.

Comment: It turns out the Ingredient model was defined twice, the second one overriding the method. Had to be something stupid like this. Sorry for the timewasting question and thanks for your help everybody.